# how to get params id get in external js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

home.vue

```
    onChange(event) {
      
      
         this.$router.push({
    name: this.$router.currentRoute.value.name, 
    params: { id: event.value.value }
          });
         }
    },
```

api.service.js

```
return axios.get(API_URL+'/product/all?id='+id, { headers: authHeader() })
      .then((res) => res.data);
```

how to get params id get  in external js file

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `URLSearchParams` (read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)) and `URL` (read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL))

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.searchParams);
console.log(searchParams.has('id'));
console.log(searchParams.get('id'));
```